# Cannot understand why more vectorization is slower than less vectorization in this case?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I meet a practical problem in which more vectorization is slower than less vectorization. I simplify the main problem into the following toy model.
In the following codes, I use two different methods to realize the same functionality. `f1` uses one loop, `f2` uses two loops. Naively we will think that `f1` is faster than `f2`. However `f2` is faster than `f1`. I can't understand why this happens.

```
import numpy as np
def time_function(f, *args):
    import time
    tic = time.time()
    f(*args)
    toc = time.time()
    return toc - tic

def f2(X, Y):
    d = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Y.shape[0]):
            d[i,j] = np.sum(np.square(X[i] - Y[j])) 
    return d

def f1(X, Y):
    d = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        d[i] = np.sum(np.square(Y - X[i]), axis=1) 
    return d

X = np.ones((500, 3072))
Y = np.ones((5000, 3072))

time2 = time_function(f2,X,Y)
print('Two loop version took %f seconds' % time2)

time1 = time_function(f1,X,Y)
print('One loop version took %f seconds' % time1)
```

```
Two loop version took 24.691270 seconds
One loop version took 31.785896 seconds
```

Comment: Sidenote: Have a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for more convenient execution time checking

Answer (score 3):

I guess that culprit hides at *f1*:

```
d[i] = np.sum(np.square(Y - X[i]), axis=1)
```

You substract X[i] from the whole Y array each iteration, which causes intense broadcasting that involves iteration in a range **0 <= i <= 5000**, while `f2` substracts two distinct values, bounded by **0 <= i <= 500**

Comment: Does this case teach me that I need to avoid vectorization involves large broadcasting?

Comment: @maplemaple no, it teaches you to avoid vectorization if the number of data points is low.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Why? It seems the gap is larger when `Y.shape` from `(5000, 3072) -> (50000, 3072)`

Comment: @maplemaple you didn't vectorize for the full arrays. you're effectively only vectorizing one "row" worth of points at a time

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know. There is another way to do vectorization without any loop, which is 100x faster. But I just can't understand the above poster's phenomena.

Comment: @mapleman The phenomena is pretty simple: f1 computation involves much more data in comparison to f2, and even worth - it involve a lot of implicit data copying hidden in broadcasting. This data gap overwhelms any benefits from vectorization

Comment: `i` iterates on `range(500)` in both cases.  In one case the `j` iteration over 5000 is done in Python code, in other in compiled code.  `f1` isn't doing any more calculations.

Comment: @hpaulj Take a look at *Y - X[i]* expression. For computing this expression it is necessary to broadcast value *X[i]* to a size matching *Y*, which is 5000.

Comment: broadcasting does not do any copying.    It's all done with shape and strides.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, `f1` is slightly faster.  But a fully vectorized version

```
D3=(np.square(Y[None,:,:]-X[:,None,:])).sum(axis=2)
```

gives a memory error because it has to create (500, 5000, 3072) array (57G).

There is a trade off between iterations and memory management.  Often a few iterations on a relatively complex task are faster than one step that requires allocating a larger matrix.  In your case there's the `Y-X` difference, but then it has to also do the `square` (same large size), before reduce the dimensions with the `sum`.

```
In [23]: timeit -n1 -r1 f2(X,Y)                                                                
1min 21s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
In [24]: timeit -n1 -r1 f1(X,Y)                                                                
1min 13s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

A variation on `f1`, that iterates on the 5000 rows of `Y` (instead of the 500 of `X`) times at `1min 25s`.  A few iterations are generally better than many, provided memory management issues don't penalize you.

### numba

An iterative, but compiled version using `numba` is noticeably better:

```
In [32]: import numba 
    ...: @numba.jit(nopython=True) 
    ...: def f3(X, Y): 
    ...:     d = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0])) 
    ...:     for i in range(X.shape[0]): 
    ...:         for j in range(Y.shape[0]): 
    ...:             d[i,j] = np.sum(np.square(X[i] - Y[j]))  
    ...:     return d 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [33]: D3=f3(X,Y)                                                                            
In [34]: np.allclose(D,D3)                                                                     
Out[34]: True
In [35]: timeit -n1 -r1 f3(X,Y)                                                                
20 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

and making the sum iteration explicit shaves off some more time:

```
In [36]: @numba.jit(nopython=True) 
    ...: def f4(X, Y): 
    ...:     d = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0])) 
    ...:     for i in range(X.shape[0]): 
    ...:         for j in range(Y.shape[0]): 
    ...:             for k in range(X.shape[1]): 
    ...:                 d[i,j] += (X[i,k] - Y[j,k])**2  
    ...:     return d 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                       
In [37]: D4 = f4(X,Y)                                                                          
In [38]: np.allclose(D,D4)                                                                     
Out[38]: True
In [39]: timeit -n1 -r1 f4(X,Y)                                                                
10.7 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see iteration in both definitions. Vectorization gives gains only on *large* quantities! You're effectively only vectorizing one *row* worth of values at a time. Python looping is more than capable of handling that, the overhead of going for and setting up the vectorized calculation takes too long in comparison here. Your `f1` isn't fully vectorized because of the iteration involved. Thus, this comparison isn't fair to vectorization, when iteration would suffice.

tl;dr have enough values that the vectorization "setup" is offset by the gains of vectorization itself.

Comment: A fully vectorized version, using `Y[None,:,:]-X[:,None,:]` creates a (500,5000,3072), which may be too big for memory!